# the transformation of timestamp to get date in Talend

Tags: date, timestamp, transformation, talend, tmap

I try to get the values from this format of Date YYYYMMDDhhmmss.
I applied this functions in the component of tMap
TalendDate.formatDate ("YYYY", TalendDate.parseDate ("YYYYMMDDhhmmss",row1.COLUMN5)) . I get the result from the year , hours, minutes and secondes but it doesn't work fo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ru23.png)r the month and the day. I got this result

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the format string should be "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html